# Can we handle nested JSON data file in Talend tool? If Yes pls let me know how( you can send me the reference links)

Tags: talend

When I try Talend with simple JSON data it could able to convert the JSON data to table format. But when comes to nested JSON data I am not sure how to do it. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: can you check this link https://help.talend.com/reader/9~rsQG6nx8ddYb3J25ruPQ/7Y6iZeLIIdacQ4JNckaing

Comment: Thank you bro. It really helped me